# Downloading...Do not turn off target on galaxy s4 sch-i545

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-4, 4.3-jelly-bean

Yesterday evening I received the update to Android 4.3 on galaxy s4 sch-i545 and figure to do updates and the phone stuck at 83% and he remains stuck at Downloading ... Do not turn off target. L `I left it 3 hours and nothing happened, still remained blocked. The phone is the global mode and use a different sim than Verizon. Sorry I do not write good English but I hope you understand. Thank you!